# Redirect old permalinks to new permalinks

Tags: permalinks, redirect, customization

I changed the permalink structure from `/%category%/%postname%/` to `/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%//`

How can I redirect all old posts to the new ones (eg: via htaccess)?

Comment: You don't need to redirect, it's all done automatically by WordPress. As far as I understand it, WP saves your posts in the DB by their post ID's and generates the pretty permalinks on the fly based on your permalink settings.

Comment: @AKTed While visiting the post at the new permalink will work fine, visiting the old permalink will result in a 404 error

Comment: Ahhh, wasn't thinking of that, thanks. Yoast has a .[htaccess redirect generator](http://yoast.com/change-wordpress-permalink-structure/), but I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: You can't do this with .htaccess, as it can't know the category or post date of the post

Comment: @AKTed Yoast's redirect generator only works when changing the structure to `/%postname%/`

Answer (score 4):

WordPress should handle the 301 redirects for you automatically in this case. It doesn't always, but it should here.

Long story short, WordPress has a function, `redirect_guess_404_permalink` which tries to find the correct post when it encounters a 404 by using the end of the 404 url to query against the `wp_posts.post_name`. If it finds a post, it will perform a 301 redirect. In your particular case, because your old structure ends in `%postname%`, this should very reliably 301 all your old paths.

Comment: Had a similar issue to OP. Changed permalink structure, but old links receive a 404. But I know that WP should handle this. I noticed that [`redirect_guess_404_permalink()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/redirect_guess_404_permalink/) guesses in a less-than strict context (i.e., `post_name LIKE %s`) by default. But you can change this using the `strict_redirect_guess_404_permalink` filter by returning `true`. After doing this, the old post link redirected as expected.

Answer (score 2):

You can also redirect via WP. Yes, the htaccess variant is with better performance, but a small plugin is easy to use.

Use the Hook `template_redirect` and check for the conditional function `is_404()`; if true, than get the right permalink and rewrite. Also you can use the small plugin [Change Permalink Helper](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/change-permalink-helper/).